# Sorting by two columns on an MVC wegrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sorting, razor, webgrid

At the moment I have a Webgrid which is somewhat like this...

```
 Server  |  Application  |  Details
---------+---------------+-------------
 Server1 |  Application1 | Example1
 Server2 |  Application2 | Example2
 Server3 |  Application3 | Example3     
 Server4 |  Application4 | Example4
```

Currently, the Webgrid is sorting itself just on the Server, in alphabetical order. However, each Server may have more than one Application, like this...

```
 Server  |  Application  |  Details
---------+---------------+-------------
 Server1 |  Application3 | Example3
 Server1 |  Application4 | Example4
 Server1 |  Application1 | Example1     
 Server1 |  Application2 | Example2
```

The defaultSort is currently set to Server, how can I set the Application column to order itself as a secondary sort in the Webgrid?

Answer (score 0):

I am now dealing with the sort separately to the Webgrid, and ordering the data in the list rather than on the front-end. This seems to offer more granularity and options than doing it with Webgrid.